# Can not able to set Request Header during Ajax call in ssl(https)

Tags: ajax, django, apache, ssl

Can not able to set Request Header during Ajax call in ssl(https)?

Added entry in the ssl.conf file:

ssl.conf content:-

```
<VirtualHost>
....
WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

JS code:

```
$.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "myBase64variable");
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          },
......
```

But in django-python view can not get `Authorization` in request.

Comment: The question does not involve Python in any way. The tag should be removed.

Comment: ok, view of url is written in django-python.

Comment: have you looked in e.g. Chrome dev tools to see if the header is really being sent?

Comment: @Anentropic: On mozill. In the Console/Net, Every URL call have request and  Response hearers.  `Authorization` is not coming there also django view also not get  `Authorization` header in request but same work with http(for other project) but not work for https.